# Can we generate a population script with Django?

Tags: python, django

Can we generate a population script with Django ?

If not, is there a way to backup SQL data (mysql) with the django framework (I really mean the data and not the schema) ? And yes, I know mysqldump, but I want to know if there is a way through the django framework to do it.

Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Django has a [management command called `dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-app-label-app-label-app-label-model) to do exactly what you are looking for. You can download the data specific to an app/multiple apps.

Example usage:

```
> python manage.py dumpdata <appname1>
```

Later on, you can use the [`loaddata` to load data into the databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata)